# $L_1+L_2$ is close if $L_1\bot L_2$ are close sub-spaces of a Hilbert space $H$

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

$L_1+L_2$ is close if $L_1\bot L_2$ are sub-spaces of a  Hilbert space $H$. While I do understand why it is true, I can't be completely sure how deduction is done here. I do know that if $\langle z_n-z,z_n-z\rangle\to 0$ then $2\Re\langle z_n,z\rangle=2\langle z,z\rangle=||z||^2$. Putting $z_n=x_n+y_n$ with $x_n\in L_1,y_n\in L2$, $\langle z_n-z,z_n-z\rangle\to 0$ means $\langle x_n,x_n\rangle+\langle y_n,y_n\rangle\to \langle z,z\rangle$, but LHS has a limit inside $L1$ and $L_2$ separately. How can I make the final argument?

Comment: First you assumed that the sequence $(z_n)$ converge. Then you decomposed it to $(x_n)\subset L_1$ and $(y_n)\subset L_2$. But $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ must converge (individually) - since if not - then the convergence of $(z_n)$ is not possible (Do you realize why?)

Comment: I do, but I don't quite see how it is done gradually. I have a sub-space with a convergent sequence $z_n$ and a limit $z$ which is of course in $H$. The next thing would be to show that it is in the subspace. If knowing that the sequence in the question above is an addition of two sequences both of which belongs to different, disjoint, orthogonal sub-spaces immediately means that the union is closed, what is this question for? Or alternately, Where was I wrong and what is the process for a good answer?

Comment: Should I go with contradiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(z_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $L_1 + L_2$. Then we can write $z_n = \underbrace{x_n}_{\in L_1} +\underbrace{y_n}_{\in L_2}$.

Since $L_1 \perp L_2 $ we have $\| z_n \|^2 = \|x_n \|^2 +\|y_n\|^2$ (Pythagoras). Moreover, $(z_n)$ is cauchy, and so:
$$ \|x_n -x_m\|^2 +\|y_n -y_m\|^2 = \| z_n -z_m\|^2 \rightarrow 0$$

Implying $x_n\rightarrow x \space ; \space y_n\rightarrow y$ for some $x\in L_1 $ , $y \in L_2 $  (Since $L_1 \space ,\space L_2 $ are closed).
 (For the sake of finishing an arguement): We then notice $\lim z_n = z =x+y \in L_1 + L_2 $